# how to get the screenwidth in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I would like to layout a UITableViewCell. For this I need to know the screenwidth of my device. Normally in ViewController I get the Screenwidth with:

```
self.view.frame.width
```

in my case this will be 375.

When fetching the width in my UITableViewCell I get a width of 320:

```
class CellResult: UITableViewCell {

...
...
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let rowwidth=frame.width; // <--- 320
```

I prevously initialized my UITableView with a frame of a width of 375.

How do I get the real width of my device in my UITableViewCell ?

Comment: Show us where you're calling this from.  Some context will go long ways towards answering your question.

Comment: Just updated the question : let rowwidth=frame.width; // <--- 320

Comment: You can always get the current screen width with UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width

Comment: Thanks Glorfindel. You can answer if you like and I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can get the size of the screen using `UIScreen`; however, I think that the proper place to access the actual size of the cell (in case you need to position your own custom views, etc.), is after it layouts its subviews. In other words, you can override the `layoutSubviews()` method in your cell subclass and do whatever you need to do that's based on the cell's frame there where its frame will be at the proper size.